# Expire date as default value for TIMESTAMP column

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, creation

Is there any way to set the default value for a column as an expire date (some hours from `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)?

I have already tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
ADD COLUMN `expire` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

But didn't work..

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns can default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but not to a value calculated by a function. Best bet is a trigger as in Ike's example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't implement a complex default value like that in the table definition.

You can do it with a trigger if you want:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_b_ins_table $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_b_ins_table BEFORE INSERT ON table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.expire = NOW() + INTERVAL 5 HOUR;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```