# How can I add 24 hours in CURRENT_TIMESTAMP MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I want to add expire TIMESTAMP in DB table. I have one field timestamp with type TIMESTAMP and default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). I adding new field "expire" with type DATETIME with default value ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INRERVAL 1 DAY), but not working.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_mch` (
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `qty_new` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Where I'm wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not supported in the column default definition.

You can use a trigger to do it instead.

See this question for details:

[Expire date as default value for TIMESTAMP column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721804/expire-date-as-default-value-for-timestamp-column/9721905#9721905)